# How can I write a function that will find the index with the lowest value

Tags: c, function, pass-by-reference

I'm learning about functions with pass by reference.

My question is how can I write a function that will find the index with the lowest value that was taken from an input text file.

The text file contains the min and the max index to create a range. the function should return the index with the lowest value stored in that range. Then function should also check for indexes with the same value within range and then return the first one of those indexes.

---

example

```
index 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

value 8 3 6 7 9 5 3 8 6 7  4  5
```

If min index read from input text file was 0 and max index read from text file was 11, the return should be index 1.

---

Function Prototype used `int findMinIndex(int data[], int low, int high);`

---

Full program

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

int findMinIndex(int data[], int low, int high);

int main() {
    int i, loop, n, queries, data[MAX];

    // Read in the schedule data.
    FILE* ifp = fopen("schedule.in", "r");
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &data[i]);

    // Process each query.
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &queries);
    for (loop=0; loop<queries; loop++) {
        int low, high;
        fscanf(ifp, "%d%d", &low, &high);
        printf("%d\n", findMinIndex(data, low, high));
    }

    return 0;
}

// Pre-condition:  low <= high and are both valid indexes to data.
// Post-condition: Returns the lowest index in [low, high] storing
//                 the minimum of array[low]�array[high].
int findMinIndex(int data[], int low, int high){      
    
     //Function needed

}
```

Expected output [link](https://ufile.io/kja9uby2)

UPDATE: I have implemented Ibram Reda's function and the program is printing similar indexes to the expected output, but is not the exact same for some reason.

This is the updated code and I have also attached a link to the output file.

```
#define MAX 100

int findMinIndex(int data[], int low, int high);

int main() {
    int i, loop, n, queries, data[MAX];

    // Read in the schedule data.
    FILE* ifp = fopen("schedule.in", "r");
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &data[i]);

    // Process each query.
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &queries);
    for (loop=0; loop<queries; loop++) {
        int low, high;
        fscanf(ifp, "%d%d", &low, &high);
        printf("%d\n", findMinIndex(data, low, high));
    }

    return 0;
    
    
}

// Pre-condition:  low <= high and are both valid indexes to data.
// Post-condition: Returns the lowest index in [low, high] storing
//                 the minimum of array[low]�array[high].

int findMinIndex(int data[], int low, int high) {

    int k = 0;
    int minimumValue;
    int index;
    // make some checks on the argument  
    if (high < low) {
        // here must be error
        // TODO : throw an argument exption
    }
    if (data == NULL) {
        // here must be error
        // TODo: throw an argument exption null data 
    }
        
    minimumValue = data[low]; 
    index = low;
    for (k = low;k < high;k++) {        
        if (data[k] < minimumValue) {
            minimumValue = data[k];
            index = k;
        }
    }//Loop to find lowest index
    return index;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pass by reference"?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: There's no "pass by reference" in your code. For your function you need to loop over the array and keep track of the smallest value you find. You should pass the length of the array to your function too.

Comment: @thriqon I'm just studying for an exam, and this has me a little lost. I have tried different loops, this loop is the last one I have been testing, I have been checking the local values and so far I think is getting the correct min and max `int findMinIndex(int data[], int low, int high){

   for(low = data[low] ; low <= data[high] ; low ++)
    {  

           



    }


    


}`

Comment: C is pass by value.  You can simulate pass by reference by passing an address, but you should stop thinking of it as "pass by reference".

Comment: @RetiredNinja I believe OP doesn't need the array length, because he takes "valid low/high indices to data". @Kakarotto if you set `low = 0`, you're losing the information you got from the caller. Either use a different iterating variable, or increment `low` like you do now but without  zeroing it in advance.

Comment: @Al.G.Ah, I read it wrong. I thought the min/max were values in the array and they were looking for the index of the lowest value between those.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Passing by address is pass by reference. An address is a reference. The word was used that way historically. C++ later adopted the word “reference” to refer to a specific feature in that language, but it does not change the meaning of the word outside of C++ contexts. Whether an address is passed manually (using `&` or pointers calculations) or automatically (relying on automatic conversion of arrays), what is passed is a thing that does refer to the object intended, so it is a reference in both an English sense and a technical non-C++ sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### implement of the function

```
int findMinIndex(int data[], int low, int high) {
    // make some checks on the argument  
    if (high < low) {
        // here must be error
        // TODO : throw an argument exption
        // update:
        // you need to handle this error according your logic 
        // you could swap them 
        // but for now just print an error msg
        printf("error happen : start index (%d),is bigger than end index(%d) ", low, high);
        return -1;
    }
    if (data == NULL) {
        // here must be error
        // TODo: throw an argument exption null data 
        // update:
        // you need to handle this error according your logic 
        // for now just print an error msg
        printf("error happen :  data not found !! findMinIndex function require refrance for int array...  ");
        return -2;
    }

    // assume that the minimumValue is first element in the reange
    int minimumValue = data[low];
    int index = low;
    for (int i = low;i < high;i++) {
        if (data[i] < minimumValue) {
            minimumValue = data[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;

}
```

## update :

i updated the code to return negitve value and print some error msg when error happen you have to handle this errors in function accourding To your logiC .. because if Function invoked with wrong arguments it will have wrong behavior ... in C language it not support error exception so i just return negative value indecate that funciont not worrking as expected...

if you don't like to print to console from function directly and you like to only print messages form the main function you code do like that

```
 int minmumLocation = findMinIndex(data, low, high);
 // cheke if error is hapen inside findMinIndex
 if (minmumLocation < 0) {
     // you could handle error here
     switch (minmumLocation){
          case -1: /*handle first type of error*/break;
          case -2: /*handle second type of erro*/break;
      }
      // you could stop the program or if you handel it then continue normally 
      // return;
 }
 // normall process when function has no error  
 printf("%d\n", minmumLocation);
```

---

### Types of Error maybe happen inside `findIndex()`

all error types could happen is an argument errors.. and it come when passing a wrong argument to function ... your queries inside the file maybe is a bad queries so you have to put some error catching technique and handling in the program

1. **first error** is if you passing start index (`int low`) bigger than end index (`int high`) so here is not logical ... so this must be an error ...you could swap them or handle it as you like
2. **seconed error** is if you pass a `null` array this is obviously an error because you can't access any data
3. **the third error** this is not implemented in function ... what if you pass an end index(`int high`) bigger than the maximum size of the array !! ... this will cause acces data out of range (and this is very dangerous in C) so to avoid this error you have to change the function signature to pass the maximum size of array then the function  Prototype will be like `int findMinIndex(int data[], int maxSize,int low, int high);` and then you could add more chek condetion like this`if (high > maxSize) { return -3; }`

---

you could submit the input `schedule.in`  file if  the error still exist !

Comment: Hello, thx for your help. The only problem I'm having now is that the output is printing 3 zeros at the beginning, and it should be only 2 zeros, any idea why is the function printing an extra zero? all the other outputs are correct. Expected output for the first 2 is zero. Expected output: `0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2...`

Comment: after more testing I noticed that the output looks similar but is not the exact same. here is the expected output file https://ufile.io/kja9uby2

Comment: @Kakarotto this function dose not print any thing in console !! ...this function  just return the location of minimum value  in range defined on data Array... you invoke this function and then you print from the main function ...the error is not from function .. it comming from quires in input file ... if you send me `schedule.in`  file i can help you